# What use are password dumps to hackers?

Tags: passwords, password-management

On a theoretical point of view, I get that it's bad to have my password exposed via a password dump because that means somebody could log into my accounts. In practice, how do hackers use those dumps, and how do they profit from it? I know they can use automated software to try those credentials on a myriad of services, but:

- they find that those credentials can be used to log in my Facebook profile: why would a hacker care?
- they find they can log in to my banking app, do they then manually swoop in to do stuff?

Comment: For the first bullet point: if that wasn't an issue, then why is there a password in the first place? Might as well enter your username and get logged in without password. Who cares if someone else gets into your account, right?

Comment: Hmm yes I should clarify that I do care, but what hacker might that interest?

Comment: Have you seen those blackmail spam/scam emails with "we have your password" as "proof" that they hacked you? That's one thing they do with it. Also, why does it matter *how* they steal your money after obtaining your bank login? I'm not sure I understand the question / what you are looking for.

Comment: No, I haven't seen those scams. As to the banking login, my question is basically what their workflow is because it's unclear to me how much they can automate.

Comment: You might need to refine your search term: https://www.google.com/search?q=what+do+hackers+use+stolen+accounts+for

Comment: If someone can have access to your monthly paycheck and all your savings, would spending a few minutes of manual work be a problem? This might be possible to automate, but it's not necessary for a good profit. Or they could just sell the information to the highest bidder that will do the work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Social media, forum, StackExchange credentials have a lot of value, and they are bought and sold on the black market. Criminals can use these credentials for spam, but more damagingly, to set up social engineering attacks on both you and your connections. Getting your mom to open an infected attachment because it was sent from your account and not a total stranger.

Banking credentials are also bought and sold. Access to people's accounts are used for money muling, money laundering, setting up lines of credit in your name, or straight-up theft from your account.

Passwords are also used in attacks on all your other accounts. Because people reuse passwords, it is possible to use a password found on a forum, to gain access to a bank account.

Comment: But wouldn't that require them to target me specifically? Or do they latch onto a victim once they determine they're vulnerable?

Comment: What do you mean? They would have your username (often an email) and password. They just try it on as many services as they care to. It's all automated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of "credential stuffing"? Google for that term and it will give you a bigger picture perhaps, here is a reference from OWASP:

https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Credential_stuffing

Comment: I do cover this in my answer